# Is there a feature like this in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<namespace:BLOCKQUOTE id="" runat="server">
```

This is what I see in asp code,is there such a feature in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

The `runat` property of asp tags simply make it possible to access the controls as data members in the server-side code.  That is, you could have something like the following in your markup

```
<namespace:BLOCKQUOTE id="block" runat="server">
```

and then in your server code, you could access it as if it were a variable

```
block.Value="something"
```

Otherwise, the data member isn't accessible to the code.  PHP doesn't function the same way so it doesn't have any need for the `runat` property.  To set the value of an html control with php and assign it the value of `$variable` for instance, you would use

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>"/>
```

This would accomplish something similar.  Essentially, there isn't a feature like that because there doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the code is run at the server and the output is the HTML markup.

```
<?php
echo "Hello, World<br>";
?>
```

Should run the program with the "echo" on the server and output the Hello, World<br> to
your browser (or on the command line if you run this from the command line).

So if you have some mark-up with this:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Title: Hello Silly World </h1>
<?php
echo "Hello, World<br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You should get a similar effect to the "runat=SERVER".

Answer (score 0):

no there is no such feature, there template-ting engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) but no `runat="server"`